# dealing a card algorithm

Tags: java, error-handling, logic

I am trying to deal a card from a deck of 52 and my function looks like this:

```
public static Card dealCard(Card[] deck){
    Card[] tempDeck = new Card[deck.length-1];
    for (int i =0; i<tempDeck.length; i++){
        tempDeck[i] = deck[i];
    }
    Card cardDealed = deck[deck.length-1];
    deck = tempDeck;
    return cardDealed;
}
```

When I call the function like this:

```
    Card a = dealCard(deck);
    System.out.println(deck.length);
```

I get 52?
Can anyone please help. Thank you very much for your time.

Edit:
Is it possible if I just get the last value before I call the function and the function will only decrease it in 1 length?

Comment: `deck = tempDeck;` what are trying to acheive with that? It's doing nothing.

Comment: 51, i want to decrease the deck by 1 everytime a card is dealed

Comment: All you are doing in your function is duplicating your original deck, and returning the last card...and in your system.out you're printing the size of the deck...what would you expect to get?>/

Comment: If you want to remove the last card just do: for (int i =0; i < tempDeck.length - 1; i++){
        tempDeck[i] = deck[i];
    } but that's not efficient. Use an index instead.

Comment: i made a new deck with length of the original minus 1 then i assign all the value until original deck minus 1. Then i assign the last value to a variable then i assign the original deck to the new deck which as length minus 1

Comment: i want to remove the last card from deck and have deck as all the cards without the last card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.  If your global `deck` variable is called `deck`.

```
public static Card dealCard(Card[] d){
Card[] tempDeck = new Card[d.length-1];
for (int i =0; i<tempDeck.length; i++){
    tempDeck[i] = d[i];
}
Card cardDealed = d[d.length-1];
deck = tempDeck;
return cardDealed;
}
```

---

As an alternative, rather than changing your deck size, you could simply keep track of the index of the last card dealt. So:

```
lastCardDealt = deck.length; // start at last index +1

public static Card dealCard(Card[] d){
    lastCardDealt = lastCardDealt - 1;
    return deck[lastCardDealt];
}
```

This way you have less looping.  At the beginning of each hand, shuffle your deck and reset `lastCardDealt` to `deck.length`.

Comment: This will fix your code without changing it much, but you are much better off looking at some of the suggestions below and starting from scratch (with ArrayList, for example). Think about creating a static-length 52 card deck, then referring to that when creating an ArrayList for each hand.

Comment: i dont have it as global i have it as a method calling another method

Comment: i created a global variable : public static Card[] deck=createCardArray(); then i let everything stay the same but it still returns 52. Is it possible to do it without lists and collection because i havent done that yet.?

Comment: Well.  Then the (local variable) `deck` inside the `dealCard` method gets eaten by the garbage collector as soon as you hit return.  You need to be manipulating a variable that will continue to exist, either as a global or instance variable of some object.

Comment: You need to make sure you are not masking that deck along the way. If you are using Eclipse, click on the global deck so it is highlighted and see if the deck in your method is highlighted... also, change your for loop, see above.

Comment: how would i do that so i change it in the method and it stays like that after i return?

Comment: To summarize: your original problem is that you were, 1. Not passing a changed deck out of your method and 2. You were actually copying the entire original array in your for loop due to using `i<tempDeck.length` instead of `i<tempDeck.length-1`. But there are better ways to crack this nut.

Comment: Thank you very much!. The first one did it!

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm doesn't actually shuffle the deck, it just copies it over exactly as it is... This will shuffle the deck for you, then you can just take the top element to deal a card.

```
public static Card[] shuffle(Card[] deck){
    Card[] tempDeck = new Card[deck.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
        tempdeck[i] = deck[i];
    }
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = tempDeck.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
        int shuffleCard = r.nextInt(i + 1);
        swap(tempDeck, i, shuffleCard);
    }

    return tempDeck;
}

public static void shuffle(Card[] deck, i, j) {
    Card temp = deck[i];
    deck[i] = deck[j];
    deck[j] = temp;
}
```

---

If you deck is shuffled already, then an array is not the best data structure for you (because the an array guaranteed to have the same number of elements. It will still have 52 elements after a card is dealt. Consider a `LinkedList`, then to deal a card just use `deck.pop()`, because then it will only have 51 elements afterwards.

```
public LinkedList<Card> listDeck(Card[] cards) {
    return new LinkedList<Card>(Arrays.asList(cards));
}
```

---

If you MUST use arrays, you could do this (this will change the elements at the end of the array to `null` as cards get dealt.

```
// this modifies the original array
public static Card dealCard(Card[] deck) {
    for(i = deck.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(deck[i] != null) {
            Card toReturn = deck[i];
            deck[i] = null;
            return toReturn;
        }
    }
    // Deck is empty!!
    return null;
}
```

Comment: no its a shuffled deck already, all i want is to remove the top card and return it.

Comment: i havent done lists yet. so how can i do it with only arrays?

Comment: @user1796681: Arrays are of FIXED SIZE. I suppose you could progressively set things to null as they get dealt... I'll edit again

Answer (score 0):

Of course you do get 52. You have 52 Cards in your deck and you do not change the array inside dealCard.

If you want to remove a Card, it may be better to use a Collection like `List<Card>` (for instance `ArrayList<Card>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `dealCard` method does not manipulate the original `deck` array defined outside the method. It creates a new (smaller) array and then lets the pointer `deck` that is defined inside your method point to the new array. But that does not change the pointer `deck` defined outside the method.

Comment: how would i reassign deck to be deck[deck.length-1]?

Comment: We have to see where and how you define `deck` outside the method. Please post a complete class definition (of course not with every detail, just that's what necessary for this question).

Comment: public class index{
 public static Card[] deck=createCardArray();

Comment: Please add to your original post so we can see it in context. It is important to know how the scopes of the `deck` variable definition relates to the scope of your `dealCard` method definition.

Answer (score 0):

Java is pass by value-reference (That means a copy of reference will be passed).

The changes you are doing inside `dealCard` are effecting on reference value (copy, not on original) passed to `dealCard`, not on original array.

One way to handle this would be return `tempDeck` and assign it to outer reference.

Comment: ohhh then how do i remove the last element?

Comment: One way is refactor your method to return tempDeck (or) index of the card need to be removed from outer reference.

Comment: but i want to return the last card too?

Comment: Ok, then you need to do -1 from outer reference after dealCard() method. May be do a check like if card != null, then reduce one card (move logic from dealCard to outside dealCard).

Comment: can you write it in code? i dont understand what you mean by -1 from the outer reference

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class called `Deck` with a `List` of `Card`s.

```
public class Deck {
    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

    //...

    public Card getNextCard() {
        //...verify there are card(s) a 
        //make sure once a card is dealt, it's not in the deck anymore
        return this.list.remove(list.size() - 1); 
    }
}
```

Then you can create a class called `Dealer` that can use that method to deal the cards.

Comment: can i do it without creating a class Deck.?

Comment: how would i shrink my array?

Comment: You won't be able to do it by passing a reference to some method. It will very complicated, specially if you are planning to write the whole game.